# how to post status on LinkedIn from android app?

Tags: android

i am making a app in which there is this edit box and a share button when i click on the share button it posts my status on my LinkedIn account i tried social lib but its of no use kindly help me out how to post a status.

Answer (score 10):

I got the answer after too much time spent to it. I have done using signpost lib and linkedin-j-android lib

As you got the token and secret token(if want to getting token and secret token you can see this tutorial for getting this from [here](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/wiki/AndroidConfiguration)) after that you can post share very easily just store this token and secret token in SharedPreference. like this way

```
LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oauthservice.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, oauth_verifier);
final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
edit.putString("linkedin_login", "valid");
edit.commit();
```

now from another activity you can you use this token and secret as for Post Share first get the consumer object

```
private OAuthConsumer getConsumer() {
    OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(LinkedinConstants.CONSUMER_KEY, LinkedinConstants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
    return consumer;
}
```

now after getting consumer execute the REST Call using HttpPost

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares");
consumer.sign(post); // here need the consumer for sign in for post the share
post.setHeader("content-type", "text/XML");
String myEntity = "<share><comment>This is a test</comment><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>";
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(myEntity));
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
```

as the shares post url so you need to set the message in the header part like above I have.

for the shares REST call see [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api)

sorry for poor english :-)

Comment: Pratik,
need your guide,
would you let me know, your code is working on android 4.0 plus
I am having error, communication fail with service provider followed by linkin api url

Comment: Hi, Pratik, can you help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971257/unable-to-authorize-linkedin-app-from-android) question.?

Answer (score 3):

Check out their [REST API](http://developer.linkedin.com/rest).

They've also [got a good java wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/) for their API.
Specifically check out [this](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/wiki/AndroidConfiguration) and [this page](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/wiki/GettingStarted).

There's an example on how to update status using the java wrapper available too, located [here](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/source/browse/trunk/linkedin-j/examples/src/main/java/com/google/code/linkedinapi/client/examples/PostStatusExample.java).

Comment: thanks for replying sir but i was hoping for a running example

Comment: The example linked is fully working, adapt it to your needs. I doubt anyone will code the solution for you.