# Unable to Authorize LinkedIn app from Android

Tags: java, android, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to Authorize a LinkedIn app to post status from my Android App to linkedin. But nothing comesup in my webview when I click for authorisation.

Here is my OwnAuthLinkPage.java:

```
public class OwnOuthLinkPage extends Activity  implements SoapClient {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button  b;
    WebView wb;
    String ftoken,verifire,outh_token,verifire2,requesttokensecret,urlM,OuthT;
    CookieManager cookieManager ;
    public static SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static Editor e;

    private static final String API_KEY = "API_KEY_HERE";
    //This is the private api key of our application
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "SECRET_KEY_HERE";
    //This is any string we want to use. This will be used for avoid CSRF attacks. You can generate one here: http://strongpasswordgenerator.com/
    private static final String STATE = "STATE_HERE";
    //This is the url that LinkedIn Auth process will redirect to. We can put whatever we want that starts with http:// or https:// .
    //We use a made up url that we will intercept when redirecting. Avoid Uppercases. 
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://smartprotech.com/1Push/WebService1.asmx";
    /*********************************************/

    //These are constants used for build the urls
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization";
    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";
    private static final String SECRET_KEY_PARAM = "client_secret";
    private static final String RESPONSE_TYPE_PARAM = "response_type";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_PARAM = "grant_type";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE = "authorization_code";
    private static final String RESPONSE_TYPE_VALUE ="code";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID_PARAM = "client_id";
    private static final String STATE_PARAM = "state";
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI_PARAM = "redirect_uri";
    /*---------------------------------------*/
    private static final String QUESTION_MARK = "?";
    private static final String AMPERSAND = "&";
    private static final String EQUALS = "=";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linkdin);
getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        wb= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webv);
        final Activity  OwnOuthLinkPage = this;

         cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
         cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
         String authUrl = getAuthorizationUrl();
        wb.loadUrl(authUrl);
        wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
            {
             //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
                OwnOuthLinkPage.setTitle("Loading...");
                OwnOuthLinkPage.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

             // Return the app name after finish loading
                if(progress == 100)
                    OwnOuthLinkPage.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
              }
            });
    }


    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("http://smartprotech.com/1Push/WebService1.asmx"))
            {
                finish();
            }
        view.loadUrl(url);
        try{
       StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(url,"=");
        String s1 = t.nextToken();
        String tokenHint = t.nextToken();//token
         verifire = t.nextToken();//verifire
        StringTokenizer t2 = new StringTokenizer(tokenHint,"&");
         ftoken = t2.nextToken();
         ftoken =   ftoken.replace("oauth_token=","");
         if(!verifire.equalsIgnoreCase("uas-continue")){

       StringTokenizer cookies = new StringTokenizer(cookieManager.getCookie("http://smartprotech.com/1Push/Default.aspx"),";");
   /*    outh_token = cookies.nextToken();
       verifire2 = cookies.nextToken();*/
       requesttokensecret = cookies.nextToken();
       requesttokensecret = cookies.nextToken();
       requesttokensecret = requesttokensecret.replace(" TOKENSECREAT=", "");
      // System.out.println("*secret**"+reqToken.replace(" requesttoken=", ""));
            getToken();

        }
        }
        catch(Exception  e){}



        return true;
        }
        }

    /************************************************
     * making SOAP request for getting nearby values.
     ************************************************/
    public void getToken() {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/",
                "getAccessTS");
    request.addProperty("oauth_token", ftoken );
    request.addProperty("oauth_Tokensecret",requesttokensecret );
    request.addProperty("oauth_verifier",verifire);

        SoapConnection connection = new SoapConnection((SoapClient) this, url,
                "http://tempuri.org/getAccessTS");
        connection.requestWith(request);

    }

    private static String getAccessTokenUrl(String authorizationToken){
        return ACCESS_TOKEN_URL
                +QUESTION_MARK
                +GRANT_TYPE_PARAM+EQUALS+GRANT_TYPE
                +AMPERSAND
                +RESPONSE_TYPE_VALUE+EQUALS+authorizationToken
                +AMPERSAND
                +CLIENT_ID_PARAM+EQUALS+API_KEY
                +AMPERSAND
                +REDIRECT_URI_PARAM+EQUALS+REDIRECT_URI
                +AMPERSAND
                +SECRET_KEY_PARAM+EQUALS+SECRET_KEY;
    }
    /**
     * Method that generates the url for get the authorization token from the Service
     * @return Url
     */
    private static String getAuthorizationUrl(){
        return AUTHORIZATION_URL
                +QUESTION_MARK+RESPONSE_TYPE_PARAM+EQUALS+RESPONSE_TYPE_VALUE
                +AMPERSAND+CLIENT_ID_PARAM+EQUALS+API_KEY
                +AMPERSAND+STATE_PARAM+EQUALS+STATE
                +AMPERSAND+REDIRECT_URI_PARAM+EQUALS+REDIRECT_URI;
    }

    @Override
    public void success(Object result) {
        //SoapObject sobj = (SoapObject) result;
        String accessToken,accessSecret;

          StringTokenizer t2 = new StringTokenizer(result.toString(),";;");
          accessToken =  t2.nextToken();
          accessSecret =  t2.nextToken();
        OwnOuthLinkPage.e = prefs.edit();
        e.putString("Token", accessToken.replace("AccessToken=", ""));
        e.putString("TokenSecret", accessSecret.replace("AccessTokenSecret =", ""));
        e.putString("Verifire", verifire);
        e.commit();
    /*  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main.class);
        startActivity(i);*/
        finish();


    }

    @Override
    public void error(Object error) {
        System.out.println("*******Fail******" + error);
    }

}
```

I am unable to solve. Please help.!